# C# || operator not working for masked textboxes

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I want to validate two masked textboxes. At least one of them needs to have a value. I have the following code

```
bool validatePhoneNumbers() 
{
     bool valid = false;
     if (!txtClientFax.MaskCompleted || !txtClientMobile.MaskCompleted) 
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Please enter telephone or mobile number under Client Section");
     }
     return valid;
}
```

If i test separately without using || it works. I want to check for both masked textboxes all at once

Comment: You don't assign valid to true

Comment: According to that logic, *both* of them must have a value.

Comment: There is nothing special about this code, and it's not related to MaskedTextBoxes. You're just comparing booleans. Boolean logic is relatively simple. Write out _exactly_ what you want to happen and explain what "doesn't work". Also, please don't use Hungarian notation (`txt` prefix).

Comment: I want to compare if either of the textboxes has a value

Comment: No, you don't. You want to check whether both textboxes _don't_ have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean logic is fundamental and simple. Prevent double negatives and write out your input. After that, you can simplify and reduce the expressions.

```
bool faxEntered = txtClientFax.MaskCompleted;
bool mobileEntered = txtClientMobile.MaskCompleted;

bool neitherEntered = !faxEntered && !mobileEntered;

if (neitherEntered)
{
    // show alert
}
```

Above `if()` checks whether both textboxes don't have a value entered. If either has one, the `neitherEntered` will be `false`.

You can reverse it:

```
bool eitherEntered = faxEntered || mobileEntered;

if (!eitherEntered)
{
    // show alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool validatePhoneNumbers() 
{
 bool valid = false;
 if (!(txtClientFax.MaskCompleted || txtClientMobile.MaskCompleted))
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter telephone or mobile number under Client Section");
 }
 return valid;
}
```